# jQuery.when, cannot get gata

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering why this code does not work.

Here is what I do:

- using an email and a key, i get the path to a script, which works;
- having the script, I do an ajax request and access a function - **getScriptUrlPersonalizationValue**;
- this function gets me a value, in this case a value for country: **United States**;
- **I am wondering why the jQuery.when and .done functions won't return the country value.**

I could save it globally, but I want to learn javaScript and I'd like an input as to why this fails.

**I have tried to comment the code, it's much better that the explanation given above.**

```
function getData(key) {

    var email = 'myemail@test.com',
        url = getScriptUrl(key, email); // returns the valid url towards the script

    return jQuery.ajax({
                url : url,
                dataType : 'script'
            }).then(function() {
                country = getScriptUrlPersVal('Country');

                console.log(country); // returns: 'United States'

                // And I pass it:

                return country;
            });
}

jQuery.when( getData() ).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    console.log(data); // returns: undefined - should return United States
    console.log(textStatus); // returns: success
    console.log(jqXHR);  // returns: Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success", more...}

});
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Returned values from functions passed in as `.then()` handlers are ignored.

Comment: You cannot return a value from your callback function.  AJAX doesn't work that way.  Your `return country;` doesn't do anything.  What does `getScriptUrlPersVal('Country')` do?  If you want to get the `country` value, you need to call `getScriptUrlPersVal` again in your 2nd `then` function.  The `data` parameter is the value *retrieved* from your AJAX call.

Comment: The getScriptUrlPersVal('Country') returns the country val, in this case 'United States'

Comment: @DanyD: If you want the county in your 2nd `then`, you need to call that again.

Comment: I understand, so the data is the return from the ajax call. Could you please write an aswer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .then() handlers are exclusive and don't share data, and as others have mentioned, this explains why the return in getData's .then() is meaningless. Better to just return the jQuery.ajax with no .then() attached to it, and handle it all at one level. You can then chain several "then's" together if you need.

```
function getData(key) {
    var email = 'myemail@test.com',
        url = getScriptUrl(key, email); // returns the valid url towards the script

    return jQuery.ajax({
                url : url,
                dataType : 'script'
           });
}

jQuery.when(getData()).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    country = getScriptUrlPersVal('Country');
    console.log(country); // returns: 'United States'
    console.log(data); // returns: undefined - should return United States
    console.log(textStatus); // returns: success
    console.log(jqXHR);  // returns: Object { readyState=4, status=200, statusText="success", more...}
});
```

This is a classic issue with using promises - you can get really hairy branches if you're not careful. The simpler you can keep the chain, the better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add property to AJAX response data instead of return a value.

```
function getData(key) {

    var email = 'myemail@test.com',
        url = getScriptUrl(key, email); // returns the valid url towards the script

    return jQuery.ajax({
                url : url,
                dataType : 'script'
            }).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                country = getScriptUrlPersVal('Country');

                console.log(country); // returns: 'United States'

                // Try to set your country to data object of ajax response.
                data.country = country;
            });
}

jQuery.when( getData() ).then(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     console.log(data); // should return object with property .country
});
```

P.S. I'm not sure that solution will work, but you can try.